# button that makes login in another site javaEE

Tags: java, vaadin

I am working on a platform made in VAADIN. If you want to see it is www.wikire.it. 
In this home page, to login, you have to click on "Accedi" and then compile textfields into the modal form that appears.

The platform has also another application (different from that mentioned before) that works as backoffice.

The purpose is to make a button in the backoffice that logges into the site with some credentials(is not important how to get it).

I am new in this platform, I have some ideas but i don't know what to do (as workflow) : 
- Rest Services 
- Web services from the site

How can I satisfy my purpose ?

Sorry if is a generic question, but I need it for my work and i don't know what to do for first.

Comment: Do you also own/implement/control the "frontend" app wikire.it? If yes, what do you intend to do after logging in? Scrape something? Invoke some other functionality?

Comment: yes, I have complete control of the "frontend" part. 
But after log in, for now, is not needed another function (it is needed for my collegues, so from the backoffice they can make the login with a button instead of copying the credentials, go to the site and make login) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this without changing much in your existing site is to:

1. use the Apache's [`HttpClient`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/index.html) library to launch, triggered by some user action like a button or link click in your ***backoffice*** app, a (`POST`) request with the necessary parameters (username, password, eventual hidden fields) towards your site's login address (I believe in your case it's http://www.wikire.it/logon)
2. upon a successful login, the ***site*** will (probably) send back to your `HttpClient` instance at least one ***cookie*** used for authentication -- get a hold of it :) (in the example I've provided -- see below -- I am assuming this cookie is named JSESSION, the usual case for Java apps creating a user session; if your site is done using a different technology like PHP, etc. make sure you find out how the session / authentication cookie looks like for that technology)
3. set an identical cookie (for the site's domain, `wikire.it` and `/` as path) in your response to the request that had been done in the backoffice (Remember: **A.** the auth cookie you receive back from the site is set / present for the `HttpClient` instance for the moment, not for the actual client, which is your browser! and **B.** handling a Vaadin event, within a listener, eventually implies a response that will be sent back to your browser
4. to finish handling the user click, ask the Vaadin Page to execute a `window.open('http://www.wikire.it/')` JavaScript call (i.e. passing your target site's address and, maybe, '_blank' as a second parameter to force opening the page in a new window / tab; this might get blocked though by a browser that wouldn't allow opening popups so... take care)

That should do it. Note that logging into a site is completely independent of Vaadin -- you just have to find a way to set the cookie for the browser and make it execute that last JavaScript call.

---

I've created 2 sample projects here: https://github.com/octavian-nita/so/tree/master/so-42927030-vaadin-login-to-site-button. [`site`](https://github.com/octavian-nita/so/tree/master/so-42927030-vaadin-login-to-site-button/site) is a very basic java / jsp app protected by a login page (the user name you can use to login is *Johnny*, the password doesn't matter) to serve as target site to login to. [`backoffice`](https://github.com/octavian-nita/so/tree/master/so-42927030-vaadin-login-to-site-button/backoffice) is a tiny Vaadin app with a button you can click to login to `site`.

For your convenience, I'm highlighting the relevant bits of code below.

**Adding a Maven Dependency on `HttpClient`**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**Creating a Routine That Logs Into a Site and Returns the Auth Cookie**

This implies you know the path used for the login action (usually what's specified in the login form).

```
private Cookie login(URI targetUri, String loginPath, Map<String, String> params) throws IOException {
    requireNonNull(targetUri);
    requireNonNull(loginPath);

    // Keep track of cookies we might receive in an HttpClient:
    final CookieStore cookies = new BasicCookieStore();

    // Build and work with an (AutoCloseable) HttpClient that uses the cookie store:
    try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCookieStore(cookies).build()) {

        // Prepare (login) request parameters:
        List<NameValuePair> reqParams = new ArrayList<>();
        if (params != null) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                reqParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
            }
        }

        // Execute the login (POST) request with the given parameters:
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(targetUri + loginPath);
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(reqParams));

        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        // Eventually, check the response to see if successful
        response.close();

        // Look for a JSESSIONID-named cookie stored in the HttpClient and return it to be used by calling code:
        for (org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie cookie : cookies.getCookies()) {
            if ("JSESSIONID".equalsIgnoreCase(cookie.getName())) {

                String domain = targetUri.getHost();
                if (domain.startsWith("www.")) {
                    domain = domain.substring(4);
                }

                Cookie authCookie = new Cookie(cookie.getName(), cookie.getValue());
                authCookie.setDomain(domain);
                authCookie.setPath("/");
                // Eventually, set expiry (to allow longer login) and other things...

                return authCookie;
            }
        }

        return null; // some sort of error?
    }
}
```

**Setting the Auth Cookie in the Browser and Opening the Site, in Vaadin**

```
@Title("Backoffice for SO Question #42927030")
public class MainUI extends UI {

    private Cookie login(URI targetUri, String loginPath, Map<String, String> params) throws IOException {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        setContent(new VerticalLayout(new Button("Log into site...", event -> {

            try {
                URI targetUri = new URI("http://localhost:8080");

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username", "Johnny");
                params.put("password", "incorrect :)");
                // Eventual hidden fields, etc.
                // params.put("...", "...");

                Cookie targetAuthCookie = login(targetUri, "/log-me-in", params);

                // We're not ready just yet: we still need to 'transfer' the cookie
                // the HTTP client received to the current browser:
                VaadinService.getCurrentResponse().addCookie(targetAuthCookie);

                // Upon responding to the Vaadin 'click' request, open the target URL (eventually in a new page / tab):
                Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute("window.open('" + targetUri + "');");

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        })));
    }

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MainUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MainUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MainUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {}
}
```

Let us know how this goes for you...

Comment: Of course I think it is the best solution I found 
And also thank you for the completeness of the answer 
It is running without problems 

And we are looking for another java developer in our startup ;)